# Submit Review Request to Google for Reported Attack Page of a subdomain that i have no ownership

Tags: google-search-console, malware

My website is JerryDelRio.com – it's wordpress install looks clean, but it appears that malware exists on all sub-domains in their idxbroker.com search. For example:
http://www.jerrydelrio.idxco.com/idx/14511/mapSearch.php

How can we make google realize that these sub-domains are good to go? Idxbroker.com is a service we use to display property real estate search – I do NOT control that domain and I am sure it is very clean.

Here is a screenshot on how to submit review request to google:
[image: Here is a screenshot on how to submit review request to google:]

But it ask to upload verification file to jerrydelrio.idxco.com. But i don't control the domain. It is just a service from Idxbroker.com

Please help me on how i can request google to review the Reported Attack page.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this account to a custom subdomain via a CNAME record. Then you can claim in google webmasters tools.